# Spark: Force two RDD[Key, Value] with co-located partitions using custom partitioner

Tags: hash, apache-spark, partitioning, shuffle

I have two `RDD[K,V]`, where `K=Long` and `V=Object`. Lets call the `rdd1` and `rdd2`. I have a common custom Partitioner. I am trying to find a way to take `union` or `join` by avoiding or minimizing data movement.

```
val kafkaRdd1 = /* from kafka sources */
val kafkaRdd2 = /* from kafka sources */

val rdd1 = kafkaRdd1.partitionBy(new MyCustomPartitioner(24))
val rdd2 = kafkaRdd2.partitionBy(new MyCustomPartitioner(24))

val rdd3 = rdd1.union(rdd2) // Without shuffle
val rdd3 = rdd1.leftOuterjoin(rdd2) // Without shuffle
```

Is it safe to assume (or a way to enforce) the `nth-Partition` of both `rdd1` and `rdd2` on same `slave` node?

Comment: The think you're looking for is called Spark's bucketBy https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/4861715144695760/2994977456373837/5701837197372837/latest.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to enforce* colocation in Spark but the method you use will minimize data movement. When `PartitionerAwareUnionRDD` is created input `RDDs` are analyzed to choose optimal output locations based on the number of records per location. See [`getPreferredLocations`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PartitionerAwareUnionRDD.scala#L77) method for details.

---

* According to [High Performance Spark](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html)

> Two RDDs will be colocated if they have the same partitioner and were shuffled as part of the same action.